# где находятся dns зоны пользователей во freebsd?

Tags: freebsd

Можете подсказать где находятся dns-записи зон (bind) пользователей во freebsd?
Я не могу найти, где находятся эти файлы. Нужно перенести днс зоны на другой сервер, и второй вопрос, как лучше осуществить перенос?

Answer (score 0):

Если под "пользователями" имеются в виду какие-то клиентские зоны, которые просто обслуживаются вашим сервером, то нужно смотреть каждую зону отдельно, так как есть возможность разместить файлы зон от каздого домена по любым каталога. На пример

```
zone "clients" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/namedb/master/clients";
        allow-update {
            192.168.1.5;
        };
};
```

вот здесь в описателе зоны clients указанно, что файл зоны находиться по адресу */etc/namedb/master/* и имеет имя *clients*. Соответственно вы просто копируете описатель из файла **/etc/namedb/named.conf** на свой новый сервер, а потом копируете все файлы зон где бы они не находились, и уже в своем сервере указываете новые пути к этим скопированным файлам.

*НО* если на новом сервере другие адреса и/или другое имя самого сервера, то вместе с переносом нужно убедиться, что домен делегирован на сервер с именем совпадающим с именем нового сервера, что в настройках slave доменов указан правильный адрес для синхронизации зон, что у нового сервера правильно указаны сервера для которых разрешён обмен файлами зон...

и *только тогда* процедура пройдет гладко